# How to hide the file icons listed in Eclipse's editor file tabs?

Tags: eclipse, appearance

99% of the files I edit in Eclipse are Java files.  On a normal day, all of my Editor file tabs show the same "J" icon which I find distracting.

How do I configure Eclipse file tabs to only display the file names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the icon is implemented in code, but more likely it's located as a resource in a jar in your installation. If you can find the icon in your installation you could replace it with a blank image file.

Comment: Thanks, this did occur to me although in the Java perspective > Package Explorer it may affect my ability to quickly find/identify Java files as opposed to text, etc.  I'll find the icon file & give this a try.

Comment: Eclipse jars are signed, you will get errors if you change anything in them.